# Proof that certain number is an integer

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $k$ be an integer and let

$$
n=\sqrt[3]{k+\sqrt{k^2-1}}+\sqrt[3]{k-\sqrt{k^2-1}}+1
$$

Prove that $n^3-3n^2$ is an integer.

---

(I have started posting any problem I get stuck on and then subsequently find a good solution to here on math.se, primarily to get new solutions which might be even better, and to get checked if my solutions are ok)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca)$$

$$a+b+c=0\implies a^3+b^3+c^3=3abc$$

Let $a=\sqrt[3]{k+\sqrt{k^2-1}}$, $b=\sqrt[3]{k-\sqrt{k^2-1}}$, $c=1-n$

Clearly we have $a+b+c=0$

$$a^3+b^3+c^3=3abc\tag{1}$$

$$ab=\sqrt[3]{k+\sqrt{k^2-1}}\cdot\sqrt[3]{k-\sqrt{k^2-1}}$$

$$ab=\sqrt[3]{k^2-(\sqrt{k^2-1})^2}$$

$$ab=\sqrt[3]1 = 1$$

Substituting back in $(1)$

$$k+\sqrt{k^2-1}+k-\sqrt{k^2-1}+(1-n)^3=3(1-n)$$

$$2k+1-3n+3n^2-n^3 = 3-3n$$

$$\require{cancel}{2k+1-\cancel{3n}+3n^2-n^3 = 3-\cancel{3n}}$$

$$n^3-3n^2=2k-2$$

which is obviously an integer.

Comment: Very nice answer! What was the motivation for approaching this way?

Comment: @Ovi of course I had to avoid direct computation of the $n^3$ and $n^2$. Noticing the $\sqrt[3]{}$ terms were conjugates of each other suggested that a formula with the product $ab$ might help. Also being $\sqrt[3]{}$ terms, they could be cubed easily. At first I thought of separating it as the $a$ and $b$ here, and $c=1$, that didn't work obviously, when I realized that $c=1-n$ allowed me to use this identity. As for why I thought of this factorization, I already knew $a+b+c=0\implies a^3+b^3+c^3=3abc$ but had never seen a proof. The next couple of minutes were spent trying to prove,.....

Comment: ....which I figured could be accomplished with the factor theorem. Turned out I was right. :D